# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not associated with a fragment manager

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

"We are getting exception when we open BottomSheetDialogFragment multiple times on the click of button.
So first of all we are removing BottomSheetDialogFragment if this is already added after that we are open it with new instance.
Please check my Code."

```
fun show(
            ctx: Context,
            product: Product?,
            combinationName: String?,
            imgUrl: String,
            selectedCombinationData: Combinations?,
        ) {
             dialogFragment = AddToBagProductDetailBottomSheet()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable(ADD_TO_BAG_PRODUCT_DETAILS, product)
            bundle.putString(COMBINATION_NAME, combinationName)
            bundle.putParcelable(SELECTED_COMBINATION_DATA, selectedCombinationData)
            bundle.putString(IMAGE_URL, imgUrl)
            dialogFragment?.arguments = bundle
            dialogFragment?.show(
                (ctx as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager,
                ADD_TO_BAG_PRODUCT_DETAILS
            )
        }
 /**
     * dismiss a dialog when multiple instance is created
     */
    fun dismissIfMultipleDialog() {
        if (dialogFragment != null) {
            // dialogFragment?.dismissAllowingStateLoss()
            dialogFragment?.dismiss()
            dialogFragment = null
        }
    }

Calling function->
 AddToBagProductDetailBottomSheet.dialogFragment?.dismissIfMultipleDialog()
 AddToBagActivity.start(context, product, false,pageSource)
```